# PHPStorm: отключение проверок для выбранных файлов

Tags: phpstorm

Работаю над проектом на Opencart, было принято решение оформить изменения кода как отдельную структуру в фс, которая по команде мерджится в установленный опенкарт, т.е. при необходимости изменить какой-нибудь `index.php` он дублируется в `src/Injection`, откуда по команде `dev:merge` заменяет `index.php` в папке установке Opencart. Естественно, при первом же коммите PHPStorm сообщил мне о миллиарде ошибок в этом `index.php`, на содержание которого мне наплевать, потому что я банально добавил туда `vendor/autoload.php`, а остальное меня не волнует. Есть ли способ сказать шторму, что этот файл вообще не нужно анализировать? Такая штука [точно есть](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html) у решарпера, но про шторм гугл почему-то молчит.

Comment: В правом нижнем углу шторма есть человечек в шляпе, его можно отключить, это инспектор кода, вот только на файл или на проект он действует - сказать не могу, ни шторма, ни компа под рукой нет.

Comment: @ua6xh, на файл, попробую при следующем коммите посмотреть, сработает ли. Но там он в том числе и на SQL ругается, что в этих настройках нет.

Comment: Если совсем плевать, то можно попробовать пометить файл как текст: ``ПКМ -> Mark as Plain Text`` или пометить всю директорию как исключенную: ``ПКМ -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded``

Comment: Тоже интересен этот вопрос, особенно интересуют ругательства на sql код :)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, плюшки с автодополнением при редактировании хотелось бы сохранить, к сожалению